# How to create awesome Pages with OOB Webparts and Sharepoint Online Tools?

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, modern-pages

Is it possible to create awesome how-to's, blog posts or tech docs only by using webparts and other tools that a already available on Sharepoint Online?

These posts often following a pattern like

```
<text>
<image>
<text with link>
<image>
<code>
...
```

etc.

Here is an [example](https://spblog.net/post/2019/04/22/microsoft-flow-guides-improve-sharepoint-modern-pages-approval-with-azure-content-moderation) of a page with a technical article (I don't know the operator, the page is a Google find) the way I want to write it.

I can only use modern pages, so the old wiki-template will be omitted. I know that the [Markdown Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-markdown-web-part-6d73c06d-2877-4bc9-988b-f2896016c50b) exists, but the handling of images is very unintuitive and complicated there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic introduction about how to start building your own pages:[SharePoint Modern Page Best Practices](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-modern-page-best-practices/)

And here is a portal about how to design you SharePoint Site and pages:[Design beautiful and performant sites, pages, and web parts with SharePoint in Office 365.](https://spdesign.azurewebsites.net/)

You can check great examples and directly add them to your tenant here:[SharePoint look book](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/)